# Decorating a JFreeChart

Tags: java, jfreechart, graphics2d

I would like to decorate all my generated JFreeCharts with a timestamp in the corner. Is there a way within the JFreeChart framework to draw on the image after the chart has been generated?

EDIT: Note that these charts are being generated in a background thread and distributed via a servlet, so there is no GUI and I can't just display the timestamp on a separate component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After dinking around with it some more, I found a solution that lets you draw arbitrarily on the image after JFreeChart is done with it, so I'll post it here for posterity. In my case, I was writing the chart to an OutputStream, so my code looked something like this:

```
BufferedImage chartImage = chart.createBufferedImage(width, height, null);
Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) chartImage.getGraphics();
/* arbitrary drawing happens here */
EncoderUtil.writeBufferedImage(chartImage, ImageFormat.PNG, outputStream);
```

Answer (score 4):

One approach would be to subclass ChartPanel and override the `paint(Graphics)` method to first chain to `super.paint(Graphics)` and subsequently render the additional text on top of the chart.

This feels a bit hacky to me though and I'd personally favour simply adding the `ChartPanel` to another container `JPanel` along with a `JLabel` representing the timestamp.

Comment: The first "hacky" solution would work, and I did think of it, but I was hoping that JFreeChart would have more direct support for something like this. If something better doesn't come along, I'll accept it. The second doesn't work for me because I'm not displaying this in a desktop app; I'm just generating the charts in a background thread and distributing them via a servlet.

Comment: I realize now, on reading it again, that both your answers assume that I'm running a desktop app, so that's not going to work for me. It could work for others, though, so I'm still upvoting it.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this forum post here:

http://www.jfree.org/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=27939

That uses an ImageIcon as a watermark:

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(new URL(watermarkUrl));
Image image = icon.getImage();
chart.setBackgroundImage(image);
chart.setBackgroundImageAlignment(Align.CENTER);
chart.getPlot().setBackgroundAlpha(0.2f);
```

Comment: I didn't really want to use an ImageIcon because I want to display a dynamic String rather than a fixed image, but I suppose I could generate an image for the String if I can't find something better.

Answer (score 1):

The [`addSubtitle()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/JFreeChart.html#addSubtitle%28int,%20org.jfree.chart.title.Title%29) method of [`org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/JFreeChart.html) may be a suitable alternative.

Comment: That would certainly allow me to get the timestamp on the image, and I voted it up for that, but it comes at the cost of some of the space for the chart render. As there is often blank space in the corner, I'd like to layer the timestamp on top of the image instead of allocating space for it.

Comment: @Robert J. Walker: I share your concern about space. You might look at `PolarPlot`, which has `addCornerTextItem()`. I usually just edit the main title to include "as of <today>", where <today> represents the query date.

Answer (score 0):

In my Experience the best way to add custom information to JFreeChart is: 
 - Instantiate a BufferedImage of the same type of the chart;
 - draw on the BufferedImage ; 
 - add the image to the current Plot, by using an XYImageAnnotation.

This is a guideline for the code:

```
// retrieve image type and create another BufferedImage
int imgType = chart.createBufferedImage(1,1).getType();
BufferedImage bimg = new BufferedImage(width, height, bimg.getType);

// here you can draw inside the image ( relative x & y  )
Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) bimg.getGraphics();
g2.drawString("Hello, JFreeChart " + timestamp, posX, posY );

// instantiate the image annotation, then add to the plot
XYImageAnnotation a = new XYImageAnnotation( x, y, bimg, RectangleAnchor.LEFT );
chart.getPlot().addAnnotation( a );
```